# "Protocol Error" during recording of RDP protocol script in Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am receiving protocol error if I select "Use Agent" option in the recording options of RDP protocol.
 Manually I can RDP in to server.
I am seeing the error when i tried to record the script.

Client side operating system is windows 7 and server is windows 2012 standard version.
Also i am using Loadrunner 12.01 community version. Client side MSTSC version is 6.3. 9600.16415 and MSTSC version on Server is 6.2.9200.16465. Installed HP agent for Terminal service on server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you post the same question in HP forum. Could you please check whether the DLL works for you?
http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/quot-Protocol-Error-quot-during-recording-of-RDP-protocol-script/td-p/6676109#.VHQ84nkcRfx

Thanks